# Update using case syntax in PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My query is working fine in SQL using this

```
UPDATE productcolor
    SET colorName = CASE productcolorID
        WHEN 341 THEN 'BLACK'
        WHEN 342 THEN 'RED'

    END
WHERE productinformationID IN (50)
```

But now i want to transfer it to PDO this is my first time using case in PDO.. So far this is my syntax

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor
    SET colorName = CASE productcolorID
        WHEN :producolorID THEN :colorName
    END
WHERE productinformationID IN (:productinformationID)');

        $stmt->execute(array(
        ':colorName' => $savecolor,
        ':productcolorID' => $testID,
        ':productinformationID' => $prodID));
```

Can someone correct my syntax? Thank you!

Comment: Did you execute this code?

Comment: add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything.

Comment: Yes i executed that code but nothing happens.. @leonardo_palma i think my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Noting happens @Fred-ii-

Comment: In the php code you didn't put the second WHEN.

Comment: I don't need to insert the 2nd when since the productcolorID is dynamic number.

Comment: In the WHEN line you have "producolorID" but in the array you have "productcolorID".

Comment: Pay attention what construction `productinformationID IN (:productinformationID)` will work perfectly only for one value in `:productinformationID`